Copy a directory in python without overwriting the destination
I am trying to recursively copy a directory into another directory using shutil.copytree() this works great to a degree.
The problem I run into is that I have multiple directories that I want to copy into the destination directory. It seems that the only option is to overwrite whatever is in the destination directory when I copy the files.
Is there a way of recursively copying the files from one directory into another that does not overwrite the destination? Googling around has only turned up options for overwriting the destination using shutil.copytree()

hmm I think you may be able to use rsync for this, although it might be a bit of overkill, but otherwise, I think you would have to re-create the logic yourself

Okay. It seemed like such a straightforward thing that I would've thought there would be a built-in utility for it, haha.

ok, I have one potential solution, untested. see the answer below

shutil.copytree(source, target, dirs_exist_ok=True) - chatGPT said to do this. I haven't tested it, but it's explanation seemed like what you need.

@OysterShucker did you at least try to read the docs to see if that actually does what the OP is asking? (I'll tell you right now, it does the opposite of what the OP wants)

Yeah, dirs_exist=True would overwrite the destination

@juanpa.arrivillaga - nope. That's why I made it clear that chatGPT gave me that answer. I'm on a phone and it doesn't have pydroid on it.

@OysterShucker you can access the python docs on your phone.

@juanpa.arrivillaga - yeah, that's great. I didn't do that.

I haven't tested this, but I think you can take advantage of the copy_function parameter. From the docs:

If copy_function is given, it must be a callable that will be used
to copy each file. It will be called with the source path and the
destination path as arguments. By default, copy2() is used, but any
function that supports the same signature (like copy()) can be used.

So, you could use something like
import os
def copy_if_not_exists(src, dst):
    if os.path.exists(dst):
        return
    shutil.copy2(src, dst)

And then just use:
shutil.copytree(foo, bar, copy_function=copy_if_not_exists)

This may work for simple use-cases. Again, I haven't tested it.

You can write your own function using os.walk on source directory and write files in the destination directory by replacing the source path with destination in file path.
This will also allow you to have any edge case handling you need like same name files in both directory.
If it's a large directory with many files you could use ThreadPool or AsyncIO[aiofiles or something similar] to work with reading and writing multiple files

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
